# Creating a Sticky Form with Option value fields

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that I would like to remember the fields the user has entered. The two fields that I would like to be sticky are both option lists that are populated from a SQL database, hence the PHP inside the option values. Im only a college student so please speak in basic terms but I would like to make my form so that once submitted the value in this drop down box remains what the user has enter and I dont know how to do it.....

```
 <select name="ClientName" size="1" id="ClientName" class="Dropdown" >
 <option value="">Please choose...</option>


  <?php  for($i = 0; $i < count($clientresult); $i++){

echo '<option value="'.$clientresult[$i]['Client_Firstname'].'">'.$clientresult[$i]['Client_Firstname']." ".$clientresult[$i]['Client_Surname'].'</option>';
            }    ?>


                     </select>
```

Comment: Into which concrete problem did you run creating your "sticky" form?

Answer (score 1):

I think what he is trying to say is that, if the user submits the form and if their is anything wrong, still what the user selected from the dropdown list will be retained so as not to let the user pick from the dropdown again and again. Am i right??

if that is so,

```
<option value="<?php if(isset($1))echo $1;?>">$1</option>
```

if the user submits the form, your script will verify it, if something is not right, throw the user back to the form with its inputs.

Comment: My project at college is for a mobile hairdressing appointment system. Basically I am using a form, where the user chooses a clients from an option list, as well a cut from an option list , and lastly a date. when they click the submit button this then generates the available times on that date, but I just didnt want my form to clear the client name, cut and date fields.... hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Use `<option selected="selected" value="x">x</option>` to have the browser pre-select an option.